# Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials for the longest element in finite Coxeter groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, coxeter-groups

Suppose $W$ is a finite Coxeter group and that $w_\circ$ is the longest element. I want to prove that $P_{x,w_\circ}=1$ for all $x \in W$.

I know from Corollary 7.14 in the book [Humphreys](https://books.google.dk/books?id=ODfjmOeNLMUC&printsec=frontcover&hl=da&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) p. 167 that when $x < w_\circ$,
$P_{x,w_\circ}=P_{sx,w_\circ}$ for some $s \in S$ such that $sw_\circ<w_\circ$ and $sx > x$, but I can't figure out how to utilize this, since the polynomials $P_{x,w_\circ}$ are not quite clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $sw_°<w_°$ for all $s\in S$. We can deduce by induction that $P_{x,w_°}=P_{w_°,w_°}$ for all $x$. Then we just need to know that $P_{w_°,w_°}=1$ , which is often part of the definition.

It's not always necessary to understand something completely to prove something about it.

Comment: To prove $P_{x, w_\circ}=P_{ w_\circ, w_\circ}$ for all $x$, one should use induction on the length of $\ell(x)$, right?

With regards to the definition of the polynomials $P_{x,y}$, I only use the definition in the above linked book by Humphreys. I can't see anywhere that he requires $P_{ w_\circ, w_\circ}=1$ to be true, or that it follows immediately from the definition?

Comment: @Bartuc if you do induction on the length it'd be descending induction. Let me check the book for the definition.

Comment: @Bartuc it's an exercise at the end of 7.11. See if you can solve it .

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is a possible answer. Suppose $x \in W$ and not equal to $w_\circ$. Since we have that $sw_\circ<w_\circ$ for all $s \in S$ corollary 7.14 in the above mentioned book, gives that for $s\in S$ s.t. $sx>x$ the following holds:

$$P_{x,w_\circ}=P_{sx,w_\circ}$$

If $sx \neq w_\circ$, then $sx<w_\circ$ and reapply the corollary for $s'$ and $sx$ s.t. $s'sx>sx$. Eventually this means this gives that $s_r\dots s'sx=w_\circ$ and the following equality holds:

$$ P_{x,w_\circ}=P_{w_\circ,w_\circ}$$

And since $P_{w,w}=1$ by definition of the Kazhdan Lusztig polynomials, the result follows.

Comment: How does this differ from the answer by Matt Samuel?

Comment: I don't know, maybe just a shorter answer I guess.

Comment: It seems exactly the same to me, with slightly more details on the induction (without mentioning the word induction).

Comment: That is true, I can delete the post if necessary. I just wanted to document how I actually did it, even though it is pretty trivial.

Comment: Ahh, I had missed that you were the one who asked the question. I still think that the way you did it was precisely the way Matt said to do it though.

Comment: That is true, I only circumvented doing the whole checking involved in the exercise mentioned by Samuel.

Comment: The exercise mentioned seems to be precisely the statement you make at the end about certain of the polynomials being $1$.

Comment: That is correct.